# How can I define my custom collate in Sqlite (in Objective-C) (for iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, collate

I need to define an arbitrary comparison method for sqlite in code. I need to be able to search for "e" and find both "e" and "é" (this is an example and the actual characters are in Persian). any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this help?

- [Define New Collating Sequences](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/c3ref/create_collation.html)